# JFrame coloration should like to this picture

Tags: java, swing, jframe, color-management

My question is a bit strange.

I want my created form  (with JFrame) coloration should be like to this picture:

[image]

Should i use a special look and feel ?

Comment: L&F not, different situation will be in case that you want to use different color scheme for Toolbar (eq. acrulat color scheme used for NativeOS) and buttons (min, max(restore), close), but you can to simulating this funcionality, everything with undecorated Top-Level Container

Comment: Maybe `LinearGradientPaint`? Do you want the shear, too?

Comment: @trashgod What mean about `shear`?

Comment: @mKorbel can you explain more clear? Or give me an example ?

Comment: @Sajjad: As in `AffineTransform#shear()`, etc.

Comment: Do you mean that you want that picture as the window? It is unclear what you are asking; try to clarify.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Should i use a special look and feel ?

there is no such built-in Look&Feel available as much as i know.  However for "Look&Feel", *"Look"* refers to the appearance of GUI widgets (more formally, JComponents) and *"feel"* refers to the way the widgets behave. If so, then we can always make our Swing component to be appeared as we want in the GUI.

Advanced responsive applications which are graphically rich ooze cool, sucking  users in from the  outset and hang onto them  with a death  grip of  excitement. They  make   users tell their friends about the  applications.

However, to develop graphically rich Swing application we must know how to render custom graphics on component, making them to appear as we want( with shiny color, beautiful texture, moving animation, nice typography). We need to learn how to layout the component properly to arrange them one relative to another. From answering your various question, i came to understand that you want to be a swing geek. Well:

- **First**,  Learn about the [Swing JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/)(`JPanel, JLabel, JButton, JList, JTable, JTextPane` etc) and various type of Event listeners and how they responds with the component.
- **Second**, Learn about the [`Layout Managers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). There are other advanced level layout manager available which makes life easier but learn about the standard managers first.
- **Third**, Learn about [rendering custom graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) on swing components and swing painting mechanism. Then about the [Font Concept](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fontconcepts.html).
- **Fourth**, Learn about [`Graphics` and `Graphics2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) class for rendering carious type of geometric object, image rendering, texturing, gradient painting etc.
- **Five**, Learn about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Swing is not thread safe, it maintain single threading rules. A good knowledge about threading is required, StackOverflow overflowed almost every day with the threading issues with Swing.
- **Six**, collect the book **Filthy Rich Clients** and read it thoroughly when you will have nearly finished all of the above.

**Now, A Demo Example for you:**

I have tried to make the application as much short and simple as possible. But there are somethings i have done to achieve your requested GUI, which you should not do, if you don't know how they work, (*for example overriding the **`paint()`** function*). In this example i could not collect a texture as the image you have provided. But i have used a [fabric texture](http://www.brewsterwallcovering.com/data/default/images/catalog/original/289-5757.jpg). The application needs to load the texture image first. keep your eye on the console. It will show following message prior to run the application:

> Please wait, Loading Texture :
>   http://www.brewsterwallcovering.com/data/default/images/catalog/original/289-5757.jpg
>
> Loading finished. Starting the Demo!

I have used: `GridBagLayout` as the MainContainer's pane layout manager. Have a look at the code thoroughly and read about corresponding extension(extending JCompononent and JButton) and painting i have made to achieve a nicer GUI(Well not so much nicer to many critics, but for DEMO....)

[image]

**Demo Source code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

/// creating the Button with custom look
class CButton extends JButton
{

    BasicStroke basicStroke = new BasicStroke(2.0f);
    public CButton(String txt) {
        super(txt);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 13));
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setBorder(null);
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0xFFAA00));

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setStroke(basicStroke);

        int archH =  (getHeight()-4)/2;
        g2d.drawRoundRect(3, 3, getWidth()-4, getHeight()-4, archH, archH);

        if(getModel().isRollover())
        {
            g2d.fillRoundRect(3, 3, getWidth()-4, getHeight()-4, archH, archH);
            setForeground(Color.black);

        }
        else 
        {
            setForeground(Color.white);
        }
        g2d.dispose();

        super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

    }



}

/** creating the MainContainer panel with custom look **/
// custom painting to with paintComponent(Graphics g) and paint(Graphics g)
class MainContainer extends JPanel
{

    public BufferedImage gradientImage = null;
    public static BufferedImage textureImg; // made it static just for easyness
    public static boolean loadingFinished = false;

    public MainContainer() {

        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50)); // setting the insets 
        // learn about GridBagLayout from the linked page about LayoutManager
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 

        JLabel usrNameLabel = new JLabel("User Name");
        changeCompFont(usrNameLabel);

        JTextField usrNameFeild = new JTextField("user name");
        changeCompFont(usrNameFeild);

        // create compund border for text and password feild with left padding 5 px
        Border compundBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                                            new LineBorder(Color.white, 2), 
                                            new EmptyBorder(2, 5, 2, 2));
        usrNameFeild.setBorder(compundBorder);


        usrNameFeild.setOpaque(false);
        usrNameLabel.setLabelFor(usrNameFeild);

        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        changeCompFont(passwordLabel);

        JPasswordField passFeild = new JPasswordField("Password");
        changeCompFont(passFeild);
        passFeild.setBorder(compundBorder);

        passFeild.setOpaque(false);
        passwordLabel.setLabelFor(passFeild);

        // working with GridBagConstraints, please check out the linked online tutorial 
        GridBagConstraints labCnst = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagConstraints txtCnst = new GridBagConstraints();

        labCnst.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 10);
        txtCnst.insets =  new Insets(0, 0, 5, 10);

        labCnst.ipady = txtCnst.ipady = 10;
        txtCnst.fill = labCnst.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        labCnst.gridx = 0;
        txtCnst.gridx = 1;

        labCnst.gridwidth = 1;
        txtCnst.gridwidth = 2;

        labCnst.weightx = 0.3;
        txtCnst.weightx = 0.7;

        txtCnst.gridy = labCnst.gridy = 0;
        add(usrNameLabel, labCnst);
        add(usrNameFeild, txtCnst);


        txtCnst.gridy = labCnst.gridy = 1;
        add(passwordLabel, labCnst);
        add(passFeild, txtCnst);

        labCnst.gridx = 2;
        labCnst.gridy = 2;
        labCnst.ipady = 13;
        labCnst.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 150);
        JButton submitButt = new CButton("Log IN");
        add(submitButt, labCnst);

    }

    public void changeCompFont(JComponent comp)
    {
        comp.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        comp.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 13));
    }

    // To PAINT THE TEXTURE ABOVE THE COMPONENTS, 
    //DON'T DO IT UNTIL YOU UNDERSTAND PAINTING MECHANISM FULLY
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
         super.paint(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create(); // cloning to work, it is safer aproach
        Rectangle2D txRect = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, textureImg.getWidth(), textureImg.getHeight());
        TexturePaint txPaint = new TexturePaint(textureImg, txRect);
        g2d.setPaint(txPaint);

        //make the texture transparent
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.3f));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.dispose();// disposing the graphics object 
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        if(gradientImage==null || gradientImage.getHeight() != getHeight())
        {
            gradientImage = createGradientImg();
        }

        g2d.drawImage(gradientImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public BufferedImage createGradientImg()
    {
       BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
       /// background gradient paint, linear gradient paint for the background
       /// Gradient paint rendering could be made more optimized
            LinearGradientPaint lgrPaint =  new LinearGradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, getWidth(), getHeight(),
                                                                new float[] { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.6f, 1.0f },
                                                                new Color[] { new Color(0x002AFF),
                                                                new Color(0x0CAAF9),
                                                                new Color(0x0CAAF9),
                                                                new Color(0x002AFF) });


            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
            g2d.setPaint(lgrPaint);
            //g2d.shear(0.2, 0);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            g2d.dispose();
            //g2d.drawImage(textureImg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
            return image;
    }


}

public class CustomApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // load the texture resource image
        System.out.println("Please wait, Loading Texture : http://www.brewsterwallcovering.com/data/default/images/catalog/original/289-5757.jpg");
        MainContainer.textureImg = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.brewsterwallcovering.com/data/default/images/catalog/original/289-5757.jpg"));
        System.out.println("Loading finished. Starting the Demo!");

        MainContainer.textureImg = MainContainer.textureImg.getSubimage(0, 0, 200, 200);

        // Starting the Swing GUI in the EDT, learn about it
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo: LogIn Dialogue");

                // set frame size as Demo perposes, otherwise not recommended
                frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 300)); 
                MainContainer container = new MainContainer();

                frame.add(new MainContainer());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The image link doesn't work any more, so I looked at the website and took something else and succeeded immediately with: http://bhf-cdn.azureedge.net/bhf-blob-prod/0043576_silver-illusion-self-adhesive-wallpaper.jpeg Maybe you find a more suitable image with gradient and maybe you can upload it to the image storage of SE?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JavaFX` which make you available some great look and feel.
I think it is better to go with JavaFX if you are looking for a great designs in Java Swing which provide better Look and Feels and animations also.
you can refer this links hope this will be helpful to you.

[getting started with FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm)

[Swing with JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/overview.htm)

Comment: seriously! Can you give me some reference of middle weight, requiring user input data validation or business model desktop applications which are using JavaFx for advanced customized *look&Feel* embedded with Swing. Or its akin part SilverLight/Flash with windows desktop applications which were born more before than javaFx. I do want to have a tech, which makes life easier than living with swing's property and its user input control, text/Graphics manipulation. *mixing JavaFx with Swing) might make easier*- well that is what the existence of such implementation will answer without argument.

Comment: [Here](http://java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/CatalogJavaFX.htm) are some example to use JavaFX. Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar, Those are demo example created to teach *"How to do things in JavaFx"*, I have asked complete running middle weight software application which uses JavaFx or mixture of swing and javaFx to achieve advanced level look&Feel

Comment: @Sage I am learning the next level of JavaFX now. All i know is it is efficient and easier to implement advance designs and Look and Feel with JavaFX and Swing integration.
but i will update you in future.

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar, thanks. I will wait for that and surely listen to you :)

Comment: @Sage The [JavaFX SceneBuilder tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html) is a good example of a commercial quality JavaFX application.  It would be nice to have a JavaFX showcase like the [NetBeans showcase](https://netbeans.org/features/platform/showcase.html), but that does not exist, the closest thing currently is the (very short list) of [Real World Use Cases on the JavaFX community page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/community/javafx-community-2158661.html).