# Is there any tool to make complex GUI easily which supports java to code the logic

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have tried Swing and it is really a very tough task to build modern GUIs of following kind 
[image]

But at the same time It would be good to keep java alongwith for the logical part as Java has a lot to offer like JAXP and other add-on APIs.
Tools like WindowBuilder or other JavaGUI Builder though make the task easy but still crappy GUI.

I wanted to know,if there is any tool that provides such good GUI and also supports java.

If not available,what those guys at Windows App Store or Android App store use to develop such kind of apps with such a nice GUI.

(I am a tyro to GUIs and doesn't know the hacks or tools they use.It would be helpful if you just touch those points/techniques to give an idea).
Please do not downvote.Its a dream project.

Comment: *"..make the task easy but still crappy GUI."*  It is generally believed that to be true by those experienced in Swing & AWT that GUI builders will only be workable once the programmer (i.e. you) understands how to combine layouts in order to achieve the desired result.  Then the 'look and feel' of the buttons & controls is further specified by setting a look-and-feel.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows App developers use C#, and Android developers use Google's Android GUI.  I guess you can code a Java Swing look and feel for Windows 8.  I don't think anyone has done so yet.

Comment: Yes, i can actually present you such GUI(*without animation* ;) ) right away in `Swing` spending 5-6 hours of time. There is already an [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525429/jframe-coloration-should-like-to-this-picture/19614383#19614383) where i have shown a mini example with custom look and feel.

Answer (score 2):

Any kind of GUI like that in your provided picture is custom UI with probably custom animations and behaviour and would need to be custom created in any tool/programming language that you choose. 
And that specific UI is not that hard to be created in Swing, but you will need to customize components and draw graphics.

***EDIT:***
Also, take a look at this book http://filthyrichclients.org/ It have some really cool UI examples created in Java.

Comment: Thanks, at least I got motivated to keep trying with swing.

Comment: take a look at the link provided in edit. there are also examples which you can download and see.

Comment: I have already read that entire book and swing hacks as well but it takes a lot of effort event to build something moderate thats why I raised the question.Thanks Sasa for your support.+1

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion about all of the different [java GUI frameworks here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358775/java-gui-frameworks-what-to-choose-swing-swt-awt-swingx-jgoodies-javafx)

Personally, I like Apache Pivot.  Its native java, but doesnt look like crap like swing.